# How to test a SearchView in an android test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, searchview, android-testing

I am having trouble writing an android test for a search bar that I implemented using a SearchView. Here is the code for the test:

```
@Test
    fun searchFriends_displaysFilteredResults() {
        // Launch the FriendsFragment.
        launchFragmentInContainer<FriendsFragment>(themeResId = R.style.Theme_Bootcamp)

        var searchText = "John Doe"
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        onView(withId(R.id.friends_search_bar)).perform(click())
        onView(withId(R.id.friends_search_bar))
            .perform(typeText("John Doe"), closeSoftKeyboard())





        // Check if the filtered result is displayed.
        onView(withText("John Doe")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

Here is the xml of the fragment that contains the search view:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_friends"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/friends_search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search for users..."
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/friends_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/friends_search_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_friend" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My problem is that the `onView(withId(R.id.friends_search_bar)).perform(click())` doesnt open up the search bar(which is collapsed by default) and therefore the typeText("John Doe") does not work.

It gives the following error:
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'type text(John Doe)' on view 'view.getId() is <2131230996/com.epfl.drawyourpath:id/friends_search_bar>'.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(((view has effective visibility  and view.getGlobalVisibleRect() to return non-empty rectangle)) and (view.onCreateInputConnection() is not null or is assignable from class ))
Target view: "SearchView{id=2131230996, res-name=friends_search_bar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=126, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}"

I tried disabling all the animations, and using replaceText instead of typeText but I get the same error.

Comment: try to give a delay of 1-3 sec before performing typetext.

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work